# C++ still get segmentation fault (core dumped) error after change stack size with setrlimit

Tags: c++, c

I wrote a C++ program in Ubuntu. In main function, I have 2-D array like this:

```
int main() {
   unsigned long long int s[11000][100];
   // some code to manipulate with s (just for initialization)
   // ...
}
```

And the program failed to run. After search the web, I know that the size of 2-D array exceeds the default stack size in Ubuntu which is about 8 MB. I tried some suggests to change stack size automatically in my program. So I added some few lines of code:

```
int main() {
   unsigned long long int s[11000][100];
   const rlim_t kStackSize = 32 * 1024 * 1024;
   struct rlimit rl;
   int result;

   result = getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl);
   if (result == 0) {
      if (rl.rlim_cur < kStackSize) {
         rl.rlim_cur = kStackSize;
         result = setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl);
         if (result != 0) {
            printf("error\n");
         }
   } else {
        printf("error\n");
   }

   // some code to manipulate with s (just for initialization)
   // ...
} // end main
```

But I still got the segmentation fault (core dumped) error. I also checked the stack size, its size is now 32 MB, 4 times lager than the size of 2-D array. Also try set stack size to RLIM_INFINITY, but failed again. Can anybody help me figure out the reason and the solution? Thank you so much!

Comment: So... just curious... why do you feel the need to stack allocate this array?

Comment: The stack size probably has to be known *before* the stack is allocated.

Comment: Suggestion: Try to allocate on heap. If is C++, then use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Comment: Try to create it as a global array.

Comment: Can you post exactly which output are you getting? And the line where this error occurs?

Comment: That's a ridiculously large array to allocate on the stack, so just move it off the stack.  Move it out of `main()` to file scope, or allocate it off the heap as @Mahesh suggested.

Comment: Even with an 8-byte `unsigned long long` this allocates 880000 stack bytes. If making `s` global "fixes" the problem its a good indicator it is stack-related. Did you bother to run this in a debugger and actually *see* where the fault is? Or did you bother to move it to a global and verify it is indeed stack-related?

Comment: Dear, Ed S! Getting this error is just an accident. Because this is the first time I put such a big 2-D in main function. I know I can fix it by using heap or perhaps via shell command to change stack size again (I hope so, I hope this will be fine, but I have not tried yet), but if I know how to overcome it, that would be great because my knowledge will gain.

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and ask why you would want to do this and for what you're going to use it, i'm too curious to let that go.

Comment: I use such a large array to solve knapsack problem in my online course. And this is just a test case gave by one of my fellow in class forum. Professor gave 2 different size,the smaller size is 10000 x 100 which I can solve without error if I put it in main. But with the test case in class forum, I failed because the size is large than 100000 x 100. The large size which Professor gave is 2000000 x 2000 which I cannot not perform it explicitly.

Comment: Yes, perhaps there is no accident for a programmer, that's because of a bad programmer like me. :(.

Comment: Hi John Owen Chile. The program successfully to compile, but failed to run. Because I only initialize 2-D array in main function, so there no  output. But when I run it, the terminal print: Segmentation fault (core dumped). The process returned 139 (0x 8B).

Comment: I moved 2-D array out of main, and it run successfully.

Comment: Attempting to set `rlimit_stack` after [Stack Clash](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/06/19/1) remediations may result in failure or related problems. Also see Red Hat [Issue 1463241](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1463241)

Answer (score 5):

Given the size of this block of memory, you should instead allocate it with either `new[]` or `malloc` and `delete[]` or `free` it as appropriate. Or, if you're using C++, you should use `std::vector` or some other heap-allocated container.

The reason it is still crashing is because it's still trying to allocate more than some limit on the still-limited stack space, before you even try to adjust it. Variables in automatic storage (that is, on the stack) are allocated *before* the function executes.

Comment: Its not 8MB unless you're platform has an 80-byte `unsigned long long`. The posted code is `11000 * 10 * sizeofunsigned long long)`, 880000  bytes for an 8-byte implementation; 880kb. That aside, I concur the stack may well be overflowing, but not because of an 8MB hit.

Comment: I'm so sorry, my 2-D array is 11000 x 100, not 11000 x 10.

Comment: @user2812045 It was only math. Ultimately I think greyfade is correct. Take some steps to debug this by moving it outside of main, making it static, dynamic allocation, etc. This answer is correct.

Comment: Hi WhozCraig, I moved it out of main function, and it run successfully. I debugged and receives this message: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: I also put this line: "unsigned long long int s[11000][100]" down to the end of stack size modification code. But it still didn't work.

Comment: @user2812045: No matter where in the function you put that line, it is **ALWAYS** allocated on the stack *before the function executes.* Placing it outside the function merely allocates it in a pre-allocated region set aside for the program.

Answer (score 2):

One solution to overcome these type of problems is:

```
Always declare large arrays globally.
```

This avoids the problems such as yours since the memory for global variables is allocated in the `Initialized Data Segment`. For more information see [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/). Hope this helps.